# IndexOf array of several arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array this way :

```
var array = [ [1,2] , [2,2,2] , 3 , [3,4] ];
```

So I want to use indexOf to splice an element.

Example :

```
var index = array.indexOf( [2,2,2] );
array.splice(index, 1)
```

Expect =>

```
array = [ [1,2] , 3 , [3,4] ]
```

But the problem is that index return -1 (false value).. How to fix that?

Comment: [*indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes) uses strict equality, so unless you have a reference to the array you want the index of, you must use some other method.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, you have two arrays with the same primitives, but the arrays are not equal.

The comparing works with the object and not with the values inside.

```js
console.log([2, 2, 2] === [2, 2, 2]); // false

var array = [2, 2, 2];
console.log(array === array);         // true
```

If you search for the **same array** with the same reference to the object, then you get the right index.

```js
var search = [2, 2, 2],                  // array to serach for
    array = [[1, 2], search, 3, [3, 4]], // array with search array
    index = array.indexOf(search);       // get the index

array.splice(index, 1); 

console.log(array); // [[1, 2], 3, [3, 4]]
```

In ES5, you could search for the index and use a stringified version of the search object for checking with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var array = [[1, 2], [2, 2, 2], 3, [3, 4]],
    search = [2, 2, 2],
    index = -1;

array.some(function(a, i) {
    if (JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(search)) {
        index = i;
        return true;
    }
});

if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(array);
```

ES6 with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var array = [[1, 2], [2, 2, 2], 3, [3, 4]],
    search = [2, 2, 2],
    index = array.findIndex(a => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(search));

if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I didn't undestand your code, there is a simple method to do that?

Comment: Thank you. But what is "a" ?

Comment: `a` is a variable which is an element of the array in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a library, you can use the `lodash` library that exposes a `reject` function.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var array = [ [1,2] , [2,2,2] , 3 , [3,4] ];
var result = _.reject(array, [2,2,2]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: By "habit". Deleted it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [[1, 2], [2, 2, 2], 3, [3, 4]];
var index = array.findIndex(a => JSON.stringify(a) === "[2,2,2]");
    alert(index);
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
alert(array)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can have more info about findIndex from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/findindex-method-array-javascript

Answer (score 0):

*indexOf* doesn't work because it uses strict equality, so you can't find an array within an array unless you have a reference to the array you're trying to find.

As an alternative, you can use a plain old ed 3 *for* loop and compare stringified values:

```js
var array = [ [1,2] , [2,2,2] , 3 , [3,4] ];

function findIndex(arr, value) {
  for ( var i=0, value=String(value), iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (String(arr[i]) == value) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(findIndex(array, [2,2,2])); // 1
```

Comment: i don't think that strict equality is here a matter, because it's compairing object references.

Comment: @NinaScholz—just stating the type of test that is used, which leads to either the condition that works with that test or an alternative test that uses an appropriate condition.