# How to use Array.prototype.includes() to find an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

**Sample Code:**

```
const a = {val: 1};
const b = {val: 2};
const list = [a, b];

console.info(list.includes(a)); // true
console.info(list.includes({val: 1})); // false
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does the second statement evaluate as false?
2. How can I properly use [this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to search for a specific object in an array of objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use Array#includes for a nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088657/why-cant-i-use-arrayincludes-for-a-nested-array)

Comment: Try [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead when searching for a single complex object within an array based on a predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;TR**

```
list.some(value => JSON.stringify(value) === JSON.stringify({val: 1}));
```

**Answers:**

1. First, variable **a** is a reference link to object. If you checking using `list.includes(a)` it returns true because it found link to same object you declared previously `const a = {val: 1};`.
2. Second, `list.includes({val: 1})` returns `false`, because you are trying to search for reference to **newly created object** - `{val: 1}`. Object may contain same values and structured the same, but they store in memory as totally different objects.

If you want to check same object by structure, use `Array.prototype.some()` and write comparator function for your case and logic.

Comment: Thank you for the input on this!

Answer (score 2):

This basically boils down to this:

```
{ val: 1 } === { val: 1 }  // false
```

Objects in javascript are compared by reference, and as the objects are at different positions in memory, they are not the same. To check for an object that has `val` set to `1` ypu have to manually search through all objects:

```
if(list.some(el => el.val === 1))
```