# Javascript includes() in list of list not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var coords = [
    [0,0],[5,0],[0,5],[5,5],[8,5],[8,0],[40,5],[5,54],[6,7],[40,0],[8,54]
]
console.log(coords.includes([0,0]))
```

The result here is false, and I am unsure why. Please help

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+includes+with+nested+array+returns+false) of [Why can't I use Array#includes for a nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48088657/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.includes` compares the values using the strictly equal operator.  Arrays are stored by reference and not by value. `[] === []` will never be true, unless you are comparing the same array stored in your array.

A way to solve this issue is using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var coords = [
    [0,0],[5,0],[0,5],[5,5],[8,5],[8,0],[40,5],[5,54],[6,7],[40,0],[8,54]
]
console.log(coords.some(coordinate => {
const [x, y] = coordinate
// This is the value you are comparing
const myCoords = [0, 0]
return x === myCoords[0] && y === myCoords[1]
}))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much.